# Setting the values of textarea with new lines

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code.
All i want is when i click the Assist button.
The data in database will be show in the textbox and textarea.
But i am having trouble with the textarea. In the database, it has new line and i cant get the value of it.
can someone help me with it??

```
<?php 
$tmp=mysqli_query($link, "select * from med_rec_tmp");
if($tmp){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($tmp)){
$rem = nl2br($row['Remarks']);?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['Temp_RecNo']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></td>                                       
<td><?php echo $row['MiddleName']; ?></td>                                      
<td><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>                                        
<td><?php echo $rem;?></td>
<td>                                                                            

<script type="text/javascript">                                                                     
$("#assist<?php echo $row['Temp_RecNo']; ?>").on('click', function(){
var txt = '<?php echo $rem; ?>';
var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
var txt2 = txt.replace(regex, "\n");
$("#rem").val(txt2);
$("#fname").val('<?php echo $row['FirstName'];?>');
$("#mname").val('<?php echo $row['MiddleName'];?>');
$("#lname").val('<?php echo $row['LastName'];?>');                                  
$("#id").val('<?php echo $row['Temp_RecNo'];?>');
});
</script>

<center>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs btn-group-justify" role="group" aria-label="...">                                                                            
<button type="submit" class='btn btn-info' id='assist<?php echo $row['Temp_RecNo']; ?>'><span class='fa fa-trash'></span>&nbsp;Assist</button>                                                                              
</div>                                                                              
</center>
</td>
</tr>
<?php }}?>
```

this is the textarea code

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:0px;">
<label class="control-label">Remarks:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:0px;">
<textarea class="form-control" style="width:100%;max-width:100%;min-width:100%;min-height:80px;max-height:80px;resize:none;" id="rem" name="remarks" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You say textarea... I do not see a textarea anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: Please post the HTML code that contains the `<textarea>` tag here - it may be relevant.

Comment: <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:0px;">
   <label class="control-label">Remarks:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:0px;">
   <textarea class="form-control" style="width:100%;max-width:100%;min-width:100%;min-height:80px;max-height:80px;resize:none;" id="rem" name="remarks" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>

Comment: Please edit that information into your original post

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but it sounds like you just need the textarea to show it's value, correct? If so, use this code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:0px;">
    <textarea class="form-control" style="width:100%;max-width:100%;min-width:100%;min-height:80px;max-height:80px;resize:none;" id="rem" name="remarks" rows="10" cols="50">
       <?php echo $row['textarea']; ?> //If you are trying to insert the value for 
                                       //textarea, this is how you do it.
     </textarea>
</div>
```

If it is something else, please be more specific.

Comment: i have one textarea, and the data are in the table, so when i click the button the data in that specific row will be show in the textarea.

Comment: @RamonPeñaJr. Well I have to say you're giving **.val()** to id's that don't exist. The only one that does is the textarea **id="rem"**. That could be why everything show's up there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is just that you have `<br>` tags in your text and you want those to show up as line breaks in the `textarea`. If that is correct, this should work for you, just replace `<br>` and  `\n` with htmlentities for cariage return `&#13;&#10;` and set those to the `textarea`'s `html` property not the `value`

```js
var txt2='this is a string<br>broken over several<br>lines';
$("#rem").html(txt2);
$("#rem").html( $("#rem").val().replace(/<br>|\\n/ig, "&#13;&#10;") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Add text with line breaks to textarea</h3>
<textarea cols='60' rows='8' id="rem"></textarea>
```

Comment: similar with that sir. But the value of testHtml is from my database with new lines. and i cant solve it -.-

Comment: @RamonPeñaJr. I was just trying to show you how to replace the chars. I edited my answer to try to be clearer. You just need to call `$("#rem").html( $("#rem").val().replace(/<br>|\\n/ig, "&#13;&#10;") );` after you add the text to the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

First, I just want for you to understand that it is generally not a well-looked-upon practice to include your displaying elements in your PHP code. There are a whole lot of template engines, quite a few are based of of Smarty (google is your friend here). [Here is a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it) that has some good and far more detailed answers about using template engines for static HTML and having them deal with the conversion of data into view. Since I don't know your experience level, perhaps look up "MVC" or "MVC Architecture" - it's a good set of rules to get you to realize that separating the goals of each of your files can help you, *a lot.*

In that same vein, if this is what the code looks like in your actual files, without the indents, you should maybe look into a different text editor as readability in code is essential, and if your editor isn't helping you keep what you've written mildly readable, it's definitely hurting you. [Here's a random article I found](https://phpacademy.org/topics/why-you-should-indent-your-code/30965) discussing why indenting code can be one of the best things you can do not only for yourself, but anyone else who may need to read the files later on. There's a whole lot to choose from, currently I'm using Brackets, but a good step-up from what you're currently using could be Notepad++, which I used for years before.

Now, to (hopefully) answer your question (as I don't have data to work with), what appears to be your problem is this line:

```
var txt = '<?php echo $rem; ?>';
```

What I am assuming is that your string may contain some kind of single quotation mark, e.g. the value of `$rem` is something like `I don't think you should go to the meeting tomorrow as...`, so what happens when that code gets printed out the browser is this:

```
var txt = 'I don't think you should go to the meeting tomorrow as...';
```

Even the Stackoverflow coloring shows the problem here: `txt` becomes assigned the value of `I don` and then javascript throws an error at the jumble of text coming from the rest of the string after that.

The quickest fix I can see you applying would be this:

```
var txt = '<?php echo addslashes($rem); ?>';
```

Which would result in the output of `var text = 'I don\'t think you should go to the meeting tomorrow as...';` and should work correctly.

If you'd like to just copy paste a row's worth of data from your database so that I could see the type of problem first-hand, I could be a little more helpful in my answer and will edit what solutions I come up with as I finish them.

#### Recap

1. Try to start separating your program logic (controller) from your displayed HTML (view/model)
2. If your text editor isn't helping you read write readable code, find a better one.
3. Try my quick solution, if it doesn't work (or someone else hasn't answered it already) please copy/paste a row of data for me (and others) to work with to further answer this question.